# how to get method form factory(in pipewire)

Tags: alsa, pipewire

The question now is, based on the pipewire framework, how to develop a plugin using a method which belongs to factory.

I am new to pipewire and not very clear about the pipewire framework.I have checked this link before: [https://docs.pipewire.org/page_spa_plugins.html],and i think we can use `handle = dlopen("$SPA_PLUGIN_DIR/alsa/libspa-alsa.so")`  to get interfaces from factory.That's right?

Comment: Now I want to develop a plug-in to call spa_alsa_open, etc., those interfaces provided by pipewire